# Creating JSON from multiple dataframes python

Tags: python, json, pandas

My code works perfect fine for 1 dataframe using the `to_json`

[image]

However now i would like to have a 2nd dataframe in this result.

So I thought creating a dictionary would be the answer.

However it produces the result below which is not practical.

Any help please

I was hoping to produce something a lot prettier without all the "\"

[image]

A simple good example

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

A simple bad example

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
{"result_1": df.to_json(orient='records')}
```

I also tried

```
jsonify({"result_1": df.to_json(orient='records')})
```

and

```
{"result_1": [df.to_json(orient='records')]}
```

Comment: I actually think the screenshots help explain the problem a lot better then trying to reconstruct in markdown. I mentioned flask becuase that was the framework I was using and ok i missed one tag. Must of had a rough day to downvote with out giving the poster a chance to modify

Comment: can you share us a few example fo your dataframe in a csv file  ? https://www.transferbigfiles.com/

Comment: you're incorrect in that the screenshots explain the problem better. it makes it significantly more difficult for us to help you if we have to open your code in another window to look at it and don't have the ability to copy/paste into our own shell. screenshots can add additional context but do not take the place of code.

Comment: added simple example

Comment: Those backslashes serve a purpose, no?

Comment: Also, can you share the data? I’m curious to try something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I think that you are on the right way.
My advice is to use also json.loads to decode json and create a list of dictionary.

As you said before we can create a pandas dataframe and then use **df.to_json** to convert itself.
Then use **json.loads** to json format data and create a dictionary to insert into a list e.g. :

```
data = {}
jsdf = df.to_json(orient = "records")
data["result"] = json.loads(jsdf)
```

Adding elements to dictionary as below you will find a situation like this:

> {"result1": [{...}], "result2": [{...}]}

**PS:**
If you want to generate random values for different dataframe you can use faker library from python.
e.g.:

```
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker()

for n in range(5):
    df.append(list(faker.profile().values()))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=faker.profile().keys())
```